# RBParser message nodes and targeting the receiver and the argument?

Tags: pharo

Trying to get some of my old code up and running in Pharo. Some method names are different but after some hardship I managed to find equivalents that work.

I am parsing my code and I'd like to check if the receiver or any of the arguments is aSymbol in an effort to match them to supported alternatives. I've managed to do this to selectors, by analysing RBMessageNode s

```
aNode selector == aSymbol ifTrue: [ aNode selector: replacementSymbol ].
```

How can this be done to arguments and receivers? Is there a comprehensive guide on RBParser somewhere?

Comment: Any particular reason why you haven't used the right-click menu item `Rename method (all)` for the selectors?

Comment: The AST route I'm trying to take gives me control and I can perform code analysis too. I prefer it to UI and/or Parse Tree Transformation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### By direct manipulation

Assuming that you are looking for cases like this:

```
aSymbol message: aSymbol message: aSymbol
```

For receiver you should do:

```
(aNode isMessage and: [
aNode receiver isVariable and: [ 
aNode receiver name = 'aSymbol' ]]) ifTrue: [
   "do your job here" ]
```

Here is another example on how to replace `#aSymbol` arguments with `#newSymbol`:

```
messageNode arguments: (messageNode arguments collect: [ :arg |
    (arg isLiteralNode and: [ arg value = #aSymbol ])
        ifFalse: [ arg ]
        ifTrue: [ | newNode |
            newNode := #aNewSymbol asLiteralNode.
            arg replaceSourceWith: newNode.
            newNode ] ]).

methodClass compile: ast newSource
```

The `replaceSourceWith:` makes sure that just a source will be replaced, but for `newSource` to actually return a new source you also need to swap the nodes themselves, that's why I'm doing a collect on arguments and return the new ones where needed.

You can view help about RBParser in *Word Menu > Help > Help Browser > Refactoring Framework*.

You can also play around by inspecting

```
RBParser parseExpression: 'aSymbol message: aSymbol message: aSymbol'
```

and looking at its contents

### By Parse Tree Transformation

You can use pattern code to match and replace certain code. For example to change the symbol argument of a `perform:` message you can do this:

```
ast := yourMethod parseTree.

rewriter := RBParseTreeRewriter new 
        replace: '`receiver perform: #aSymbol'
        with: '`receiver perform: #newSelector'.

(rewriter executeTree: ast) ifTrue: [
    yourMethod class compile: ast newSource ]
```

You can learn more about the pattern matching syntax in the help topic *Word Menu > Help > Help Browser > Refactoring Framework > Refactoring Engine > RBPatternParser …*. I thing that **MatchTool** from pharo catalog can greatly help you in testing the match expressions (it also has a dedicated help topic about the matching syntax) while **RewriteTool** can help you to preview how your code will be transformed.

Comment: I see. I can't seem to get it to work... replacing the receiver is as simple as aNode receiver name: or aNode receiver: and I have to create a receiver node?

Comment: @unmircea you need to provide more context. Because it depends on what you want to achieve. Wrap a variable with a message send, or just rename a variable. Because what could work for you are also transformation rules, where you can say transform `aSymbol `@message: `@args` into `aSymbol yourMessage `@message: `@args`. Otherwise you have to manipulate the AST ask if for `newSource` and compile the source code you've got

Comment: What I've got working is renaming the selectors with something like "aNode selector == oldSelector ifTrue: [ aNode selector: newSelector ]." and then I recompile. Now the problem I've got is I use a lot of "aReceiver perform: #oldSelector" and "aReceiver doSomething: 'oldSelector' asSymbol". They use the symbol I'm trying to replace directly or via string so I need a way to change that to "aReceiver perform: #newSelector" using your AST method. The "aString asSymbol" is a bit more complex.

Comment: @unmircea I've added another section to the answer about matching and rewriting code. I think it's more suitable in your cease

Comment: I'm back with results, sorry for dragging this along and thank you for taking the time to explain. Had success with "( aLiteralNode value isLiteral and: [ aLiteralNode value == #oldSymbol ] ) ifTrue: [ ( Transcript show: 'HIT' )" so I'm getting hits that there are a lot of them out there. Replacing isn't that obvious "aLiteralNode replaceSourceWith: (RBLiteralValueNode value: #newSymbol" doesn't work. What I'm doing is defining a new formatter class and adding my code in visitLiteralNode: aLiteralNode

Comment: @unmircea I've updated my answer again. But why do you want to manually tweak the AST nodes if you can just use the rewrite engine to change `\`receiver perform: #aSymbol` into `\`receiver perform: #newSelector`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133822/discussion-between-unmircea-and-uko).